# can't resolve drawable symbol

Tags: android, xml

After i add an activity,‘NavigationVew’ in the previous activity display error that "can't resolve drawable symbol

```
package com.eight.zhan.kitchen;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationVew.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
,MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener {  
}
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eight.zhan.kitchen"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

}

The error message diaplay "package NavigationVew does not exist"
why？

Comment: Have you tried "invalidate caches/restart" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationVew mean nothing，it should be NavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

i  think need following two steps

1. Clean Project.
2. Rebuild Project.